# How can I prevent this class from instantiating?

Tags: javascript

I am using a [jQuery plugin](https://gist.github.com/gotoAndBliss/5239816) for creating classes. But I don't want my classes to be initialized unless I want them to. How can I prevent the following code from initializing, but be accessible if need be?

```
window.classes.my_custom_class = new(Class.extend({
 init: function() {
    // stuff()
  }
}));
```

Comment: by looking at the plugin the only way is to either modify the plug in, or don't use init

Comment: Is there any difference between [that gist](https://gist.github.com/gotoAndBliss/5239816) and the [original script from this article](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)?

Comment: And no, it's no jQuery plugin!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating a singleton, you do not use classes at all. Just follow the default [module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript). In your case:

```
window.classes.my_custom_module = {
    init: function() {
        // stuff()
    }
};
```

Or did you want an actual ["class"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13418980/1048572), i.e. a constructor function? Then avoid that `new` keyword there!

```
window.classes.my_custom_class = Class.extend({
    init: function() {
        // stuff()
    }
});

// later:
var instance = new classes.my_custom_class();
```